# Making the scrolling div stop at the bottom

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to get this div to stop at the bottom but for some reason once it reaches the bottom it starts jumping around.

Any ideas?  It seems like even when `bottom_offset < 181` it still keeps changing the css `top` property.

```
    <script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
      var el = jQuery('#contactBox');
      top_offset = jQuery('#contactBox').offset().top - 60;
      var box_height = el.height();

      jQuery(window).scroll(function() {
        var scroll_top = jQuery(window).scrollTop();
        var bottom_offset = jQuery(document).height() - scroll_top - box_height;
        var new_top_offset = jQuery(document).height() - box_height - 100;

        if ((scroll_top > top_offset) && (bottom_offset > 180))  {
          el.css('top', scroll_top - top_offset);
        }
        else if ((scroll_top > top_offset) && (bottom_offset < 181)) {
          el.css('top', new_top_offset);
        }
        else {
          el.css('top', '');
        }
    });
    });
    </script>
```

Comment: If you could post some html and css so we can see whats happening.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how the html and css is setup so I'm taking a guess.

If the div has a fixed position, you can remove the following code and it should stop at the bottom.

The new_top_offset made the div jump down when i scrolled near the bottom.

```
else if ((scroll_top > top_offset) && (bottom_offset < 181)) {
          el.css('top', new_top_offset);
        }
        else {
          el.css('top', '');
```

Answer (score 0):

Well I went ahead and changed it so that it worked a bit differently. It would just calculate body height minus footer height and also do scroll top + height of the scrolling div, and then it only changes css if total_height < body_height.

Here's the code if anyone needs it in the future.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  var el = jQuery('#contactBox');
  top_offset = jQuery('#contactBox').offset().top - 60;
  var box_height = el.height();

  jQuery(window).scroll(function() {
    var scroll_top = jQuery(window).scrollTop();
    var total_height = scroll_top + box_height;
    var body_height = jQuery('body').outerHeight() - 150;

    if ((scroll_top > top_offset) && (total_height < body_height))  {
      el.css('top', scroll_top - top_offset);
    }
});
});
```